# Azure - BizTalk Server

Tags: azure, biztalk

I created a BizTalk VM on Azure (Trial version). I can get to the console but I cannot connect it to an existing group. Where is the BizTalk database? Do I need to create that also. Do I need to create a BizTalk Service? I am new to BizTalk and definitely BizTalk on Azure so forgive me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BizTalk trial edition image has BizTalk and SQL installed but it does not have a group pre-configured.

To use it you will first need to run the [BizTalk Configuration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248696%28v=bts.80%29.aspx) and create a group on the local SQL Server before you can see it in the BizTalk Administration Console.

The configuration tool will create all the necessary databases on the local SQL Server (or any other SQL Server you will point it at) and create the BizTalk Windows Services as needed.

It's worth noting that non-trial editions of BizTalk server do not include a local SQL Server as these are targeting the recommended architecture for a BizTalk farm whereby the SQL Servers are dedicated and separate from any BizTalk servers

This is highlighted in the [announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalk_server_team_blog/archive/2013/04/16/announcing-biztalk-server-2013-in-windows-azure-infrastructure-services.aspx) of the availability of these images

Comment: Where is the configuration tool on the VM? According the the directions you pointed me to, it is not under "All Programs".

Comment: The VM is Windows Server 2012, with no shortcuts to anything. I have to go through Windows Explorer just to get to the EXE to launch the console.

Comment: I found it. It is in the BizTalk install folder named Configuration.exe

Comment: ...and being Windows 2012 I tend to just go to the start screen and type BizTalk Config

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to [configure a number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248711.aspx) of elements. Steps include

```
> Create the Domain User Accounts and Groups [standard and enterprise]
> Create a SQL Server virtual machine [standard and enterprise]
> Configure using BizTalk Configuration [evaluation, standard and enterprise]
```

Comment: Hi Jason - this is not accurate as far as the trial edition specifically is concerned. this edition's image is deliberately designed to keep entry barrier low and so one can use a single machine setup with a local user which keeps setup simple. of course you are correct that this is not the recommended setup and so is only useful for early evaluation of the platform.

Comment: Thanks Yossi, hadn't appreciated this. The MSDN documentation I linked to does mention this.